# What's the purpose of this bitwise AND operator?

Tags: php, mysql

The code is  basic php  code for a cms,It read Mysql content to render web page based on three different methods ,by id,name or special type(index page,sitemap page ...).But I can't understand this line  "   **$r=dbRow("select * from pages where special&$v limit 1");**" what is the bitwise AND supposed to do ?

```
<?php
class Page{
    static $instances             = array();
    static $instancesByName     = array();
    static $instancesBySpecial   = array();
    function __construct($v,$byField=0,$fromRow=0,$pvq=0){
        # byField: 0=ID; 1=Name; 3=special
        if (!$byField && is_numeric($v)){ // by ID
            $r=$fromRow?$fromRow:($v?dbRow("select * from pages where id=$v limit 1"):array());
        }
        else if ($byField == 1){ // by name
            $name=strtolower(str_replace('-','_',$v));
            $fname='page_by_name_'.md5($name);
            $r=dbRow("select * from pages where name like '".addslashes($name)."' limit 1");
        }
        else if ($byField == 3 && is_numeric($v)){ // by special
            $fname='page_by_special_'.$v;
            $r=dbRow("select * from pages where special&$v limit 1");
        }
        else return false;
        if(!count($r || !is_array($r)))return false;
        if(!isset($r['id']))$r['id']=0;
        if(!isset($r['type']))$r['type']=0;
        if(!isset($r['special']))$r['special']=0;
        if(!isset($r['name']))$r['name']='NO NAME SUPPLIED';
        foreach ($r as $k=>$v) $this->{$k}=$v;
        $this->urlname=$r['name'];
        $this->dbVals=$r;
        self::$instances[$this->id] =& $this;
        self::$instancesByName[preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/','-',strtolower($this->urlname))] =& $this;
        self::$instancesBySpecial[$this->special] =& $this;
        if(!$this->vars)$this->vars='{}';
        $this->vars=json_decode($this->vars);
    }
    function getInstance($id=0,$fromRow=false,$pvq=false){
        if (!is_numeric($id)) return false;
        if (!@array_key_exists($id,self::$instances)) self::$instances[$id]=new Page($id,0,$fromRow,$pvq);
        return self::$instances[$id];
    }
    function getInstanceByName($name=''){
        $name=strtolower($name);
        $nameIndex=preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9/]#','-',$name);
        if(@array_key_exists($nameIndex,self::$instancesByName))return self::$instancesByName[$nameIndex];
        self::$instancesByName[$nameIndex]=new Page($name,1);
        return self::$instancesByName[$nameIndex];
    }
    function getInstanceBySpecial($sp=0){
        if (!is_numeric($sp)) return false;
        if (!@array_key_exists($sp,$instancesBySpecial)) $instancesBySpecial[$sp]=new Page($sp,3);
        return $instancesBySpecial[$sp];
    }
}
```

Comment: That is nothing, just a bad practice in the field name. If the `$v` value is `abc`, then the field name will be `special&abc`.

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer if we don't know what `$v` is (I just think it's a number, or some sort of ID) and what `special` contains. Anyway, if you meet who wrote this code, please slap him in the face.

Comment: It looks like this kind of coding is allowed by MySQL.  In this case if $special is a number and $v is a number, then the query selects pages according to their special value that results from the bitwise  AND; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `pages.special` contains a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) (that is, each bit position in its values would flag some application-specific property).

Then, to find records that have certain properties, one would perform a bitwise `AND` operation with the desired "mask"—bit positions in the result are set *only if* the same position was set in *both* the value and the mask.  A complete truth-table for a 2-bit value would look like this:

```
+---------+------+------------+
|  value  | mask | value&mask |
+---------+------+------------+
|    0b00 | 0b00 |       0b00 |
|    0b01 | 0b00 |       0b00 |
|    0b10 | 0b00 |       0b00 |
|    0b11 | 0b00 |       0b00 |
|    0b00 | 0b01 |       0b00 |
|    0b01 | 0b01 |       0b01 |
|    0b10 | 0b01 |       0b00 |
|    0b11 | 0b01 |       0b01 |
|    0b00 | 0b10 |       0b00 |
|    0b01 | 0b10 |       0b00 |
|    0b10 | 0b10 |       0b10 |
|    0b11 | 0b10 |       0b10 |
|    0b00 | 0b11 |       0b00 |
|    0b01 | 0b11 |       0b01 |
|    0b10 | 0b11 |       0b10 |
|    0b11 | 0b11 |       0b11 |
+---------+------+------------+
```

For example, suppose the lowest-order bit is a flag that the respective page "is readonly"; and the next bit that the page "requires moderation"—a value of (decimal) 2, or `0b10`, would indicate that the page is *not* readonly but *does* require moderation.  So, to find all pages that *either* are readonly or require moderation, one could do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (special & 0b11) != 0
```

Because MySQL doesn't have true boolean types (but instead treats zero as false and non-zero as true), the filter expression can be abbreviated:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE special & 0b11
```

We could also state the mask in decimal, rather than binary, form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE special & 3
```

And, if so desired, apply a `LIMIT` to the query (although in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, the result is indeterminate):

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE special&3 LIMIT 1
```

Given that is all we have to work with (from the code that you have shown), we can only say the following:

**The query selects all columns of an indeterminate record from the `pages` table for which the value of `special` has at least one of the same bits set as in the mask `$v`.**

Since the semantics of `special` and `$v` (and the bit positions within them) are application-specific, it is impossible for one to say anything more without a deeper understanding of your application.

Note that, whilst compact, filtering using a mask on a bit field is not sargable—so this tends to be very poor database design.